# git get the horizontal line in git command

Tags: git, git-branch

I just add some new files, modifies, one folder in my git repo, I use git branch to display my local git repository, I get below results:

```
$ git branch
  -
  dev_game_v3
* master
```

what's the meaning of the horizontal line? any error here about my repo?

Comment: Could it be somehow broken branch name? What does `grep branch .git/config` say?

Answer (score 2):

That must be some broken branch name. While it seems impossible to create such a branch with `git` cli, I managed to reproduce this behaviour by the command:

```
cp .git/refs/heads/master .git/refs/heads/-
```

Please check that folder.

Comment: yes, really, I found a .git/refs/heads/- in folder. helpful, think you.